# Mapbox GL - how to change the width of geojson line on hover?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a mapbox map, where I add various geojson lines. I add them like this

```
map.addSource('diklodartlo', diklodartlo);
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'diklodartlo',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'diklodartlo',
            'layout': {
                'line-cap': 'round',
                'line-join': 'round'
            },
            'paint': {
                'line-opacity': 0.75,
                'line-color': '#747474',
                'line-width': 2
            }
        });
```

Each line has also a corresponding marker, which on hover displays popup with additional information about the trail. N**ow I want also to "highlight" corresponding line** - increase its "line-width" so the user knows which line is selected.
My idea is to take id property from the marker, pair it with id property of the line and then change the line "line-width". But its easier said than done - I know how to get property of the selected marker, but dont know how to access the layer and change the width of the line at the runtime. Could someone advise me how to do it?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was quite simple after all, mapbox has a property for it.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty

Looks like this:

```
map.setPaintProperty(//hovered trail//, 'line-width', //desired width//);
```

Comment: But what is the `//hovered trail//`?? Is it maybe `e.features[0].id` in the hover handler? Because that one is empty for me, even though it is filled for a similar layer of type Circle. Is it the layer name? If I use the layer name, it colours the **whole** layer; and I get the impression that you colour only one of the lines in the layer (in your case, a single trail in the layer and not all the trails in the layer).

Comment: I've solved my problem by adding `generateId: true` to my source definition; I have the id now, in `e.features[0].id`.